# What is the correct way to apply contrapositive law in a proposition using universal quantifiers? Its possible to eliminate the quantifier?

Tags: propositional-calculus, quantifier-elimination

I reach the following conclusion during a proof: $(\forall x)(\forall y)([y < x \Rightarrow H(y) < H(x)])$, the contrapositive of this statment is $(\forall x)(\forall y)([H(x) \leq H(y) \Rightarrow x \leq y])$ or should I modify something in the universal quantifiers too? and what about the quantifiers elimination, its possible to do this in a simple case like this one?

Comment: strictly speaking that formula doesn't _have_ a contrapositive, since it's not of the form $A\implies B$.

Comment: Looks right to me. You can ignore the quantifiers and treat $x$ ,$y$ as free variables within the inner formula.

Comment: Thanks for answers, @DavidC.Ullrich If I consider $y<x$ as $A$ and $H(y) < H(x)$ as $B$, its not valid to consider the inner formula $A \Rightarrow B$ and apply contrapositive law like user3257842 said?

Comment: exactly what is the complete definition of "contrapositive" in the book or course or whatever?

Comment: The author just says at an exercise to show that $A \Rightarrow B$ has the same truth table as $(\neg B) \Rightarrow (\neg A)$ and quote the exercise as (Law of Contrapositives )

Comment: I just wonder, why someone just downvoted this question after two months and which already answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contraposition is correct.

If you form the contraposition of an implicative subformula, then the resulting formula will be logically equivalent after substituting the implication for the contraposition, and the rest of the formula remains unchanged, so you don't  tinker with the quantifiers around the
implication.

As for quantifier eliminiation: This formula has two universal quantifiers in front, which can be directly eliminated, yielding again just

$$H(x) \leq H(y) \Rightarrow x \leq y$$

Comment: But the original statment is $[y < x \Rightarrow H(y) < H(x)]$, I used $\leq$ because a swaped order of the elements. I got $[H(y) \geq H(x) \Rightarrow y \geq x]$ but I wrote its as $[H(x) \leq H(y) \Rightarrow x \leq y]$.

Comment: Oh yes, of course. Sorry for overseeing that! In this case, your contraposition is perfectly right, and you can drop the universal quantifiers if you want.

Comment: I cant edit the implication because its just two characters, but the concequent site need to swap the order, it should be $y \geq x$ instead $x \geq y$, I accept your answer since it removed my doubt. Just fix this in case someone come to read this topic.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I fixed it.